# C - How to convert the data type 'int' from host to network

Tags: c

We have `htons` and `htonl` to convert short/long types from host to network. What about the type of `int`?

Thanks!

Comment: `man htons`. It lists all of the variants.

Comment: promote it to long before transmit and cast back to int ofter receive

Comment: I think the naming convention with 's' and 'l' suffixes is poor. Perhaps they should have been 16 and 32, as in number of bits.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the size of `int`.  If it's 32-bit, use `htonl` and `ntohl`.  If it's 16-bit, use `htons` and `ntohs`.

If it's 64-bit, there's no standard function for that, so you'd have to roll your own.  Here's an example of how you can do this in a portable way (i.e. doesn't depend on endianness):

```
uint64_t htonll(uint64_t x)
{
    uint64_t result;
    unsigned char *c;

    c = (unsigned char *)&result;
    c[0] = x >> 56;
    c[1] = (x >> 48) & 0xFF;
    c[2] = (x >> 40) & 0xFF;
    c[3] = (x >> 32) & 0xFF;
    c[4] = (x >> 24) & 0xFF;
    c[5] = (x >> 16) & 0xFF;
    c[6] = (x >> 8) & 0xFF;
    c[7] = x & 0xFF;
    return result;
}

uint64_t ntohll(uint64_t x)
{
    uint64_t result;
    unsigned char *c;

    c = (unsigned char *)&x;
    result = (uint64_t)c[7];
    result |= (uint64_t)c[6] << 8;
    result |= (uint64_t)c[5] << 16;
    result |= (uint64_t)c[4] << 24;
    result |= (uint64_t)c[3] << 32;
    result |= (uint64_t)c[2] << 40;
    result |= (uint64_t)c[1] << 48;
    result |= (uint64_t)c[0] << 56;
    return result;
}
```